# How are the series Firefly and the movie Serenity linked?

Tags: firefly, serenity

The series *Firefly* and the movie *Serenity* share similar concepts and similar characters. Are they a part of the same story? Are they linked? If not can someone explain why two very similar programs were created? If they are linked can someone explain the link to me?

I realize they both have the same plot line, a girl is used by the government for some secret experiment. I just want to know the connection.

Comment: Also Serenity is the name of the ship.

Comment: To be fair, they don't share "similar" concepts and characters, they have exactly the same characters portrayed by exactly the same actors using exactly the same concepts.

Comment: you need to watch series2 to understand the link

Comment: @Naib series 2?

Comment: @Naib - Now, *that*'s a cruel joke.

Comment: Cruel Cruel Joke.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

They go hand in hand. The movie takes place some time after the series.

After the series was canceled, it continued to garner a large following and Joss Whedon was able to secure the funds to do a movie.

I see the movie as a chance to wrap up the series on his terms. And as a goodbye from the cast and crew.

Comment: Thank you, are new they had to be associated. So the series came first than the brilliant movie. Well they were both brilliant, Firefly and Serenity.

Comment: Now if only they would make several sequels to Serenity....

Comment: @BBlake: He did kill off some major characters, and eliminated the reason the federation was hunting for River, so I think it was meant to be a final wrapping up of the series.

Comment: well then, prequels!

Comment: Budget $40M; worldwide gross $38.8M.  In the end, with rentals and purchases, I imagine it still made money, but probably not enough money to risk a sequel, unfortunately.

Comment: If only our tastes weren't in the minority! Have no fear though, we'll get another Yogi Bear movie!

Comment: It's a pity really. Serenity/Firefly's popularity is only growing with time...

Comment: Why not?  It worked for Star Trek.  Give it a few more years and I bet there will be another movie, whether prequel or sequel.  And as for killing off characters, Joss does that all the time.  Not surprising at all.  And they keep right on going.

Comment: @BBlake don't you mean right on dieing... lol. Long live the Serenity!

Comment: When Joss Whedon is writing the scripts... :)

Comment: @Kyralessa Typically, cult-classic stuff with a small but very keen fanbase (Browncoats are *the* prime example of such a group, I think) sells much better on DVD than in cinema release. Wouldn't surprise me if the DVD sales totalled much higher than box office take, though I can't find any definite figures online.

Comment: @OmegaCentauri It could always be a prequel to Serenity.  Either taking place at the same time as the series or sometime after the series but before the events in Serenity.

Comment: @BBlake According to Wikipedia (which references [this video of Whedon at a convention](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90629pmvPZU#t=3m59s)), the characters killed off were written out because the actors didn’t want to contractually commit to sequels. DISPLEASE JOSS AT YOUR PERIL, ACTORS.

Answer (score 30):

- The TV series [*Firefly*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_%28TV_series%29) is first in consumption order, and is the basic location in the timeline for comparisons.
- The comics [*Those Left Behind*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity%3a_Those_Left_Behind) and [*Better Days*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1595821627) are set between the TV series and the film.  These answer some questions left open in both the TV series and movie, so could be read either between the two (chronological order) or after the movie (publication order).
- The comic [*The Shepard's Tale*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1595825614) covers a time period that extends from well before the start of *Firefly* to immediately before the movie.  It contains a moderate spoiler for the movie, so is best read afterwards.
- The movie [*Serenity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity_%28film%29) is set some time after the TV series and those comics.
- The comic [*Float Out*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003OEXO7U) is set shortly after the movie.  It contains a significant spoiler from the movie, so should be read after it.

Creator Joss Whedon switched studios because Fox wasn't willing to let him do the movie. He created the comics to bridge the missing characters out. The comics are an important, although not vital, bridge.

Originally, the plot line was supposed to resolve over several seasons; when Fox canceled, Joss felt he needed to complete the primary enigma arcs (Reavers, River). The movie gave him the chance to do so.

The comics are also part of 'verse canon. They are primarily written by Joss' brother, with Joss' approval, exploring other areas of the story of Mal and associates.